# Is it possible to choose specific thread to run similar tasks in thread pool in java?

Tags: java

For example i have thread pool of 8 threads, i want 4 similar tasks to be run by thread 1 in pool other 4 tasks to be run by thread 2 in the pool and so on

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it matters so much which thread a certain instruction runs on?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, because on the basis of thread name I want to perform different actions.

Comment: Create multiple thread pools for each group of tasks

Comment: Adding to @ErwinBolwidt 's comment, you can use a single thread executor for each group of tasks. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) guarantees that the submitted tasks on each single thread executor will be executed sequentially. You may consider also using a `Map<String, ExecutorService>` which will map custom names to thread pools.

Comment: it means i should create separate pools per groups of tasks, but there is no other way ? to choose a specific thread in the pool when i am submitting tasks to pool

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to choose specific thread to run similar tasks in thread pool in java?

No.  At least, not using any of the standard Java SE `ExecutorService` implementations.

Of course, you *could* implement your own thread pool from the ground up that scheduled tasks to threads in the pool any way you choose.  It is just a lot of complicated code to write, debug and maintain.

---

Your reason for wanting this seems contrived to me.  (It seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).)

> .... because on the basis of thread name I want to perform different actions.

There are other ways to achieve that goal:

- You could use a `ThreadLocal` to store the notional name, and have your tasks set it when they start.
- Your tasks could call `Thread.setName()` on the current thread on startup<sup>1</sup>.
- You could just store the notional name in variable in your task object.
- You could just use multiple thread pools, and submit to different ones depending on the action you want to perform.

Note that by scheduling specific tasks to a single named thread, you would be creating a concurrency bottleneck for those tasks.

---

<sup>1 - IMO, this particular option stinks ...</sup>